# Why do curly braces break this loop?

Tags: macros, plain-tex

I was trying to solve 'Exercise 20.20' from the TeX Book which asks to create a macro `\punishment` capable of repeating a given sentence n times using the Plain TeX format. My first attempt was the following:

```
% not working
\def\punishment#1#2{
    \newcount\ii\ii=0
    \loop {
        \advance\ii by 1 
        \message{\the\ii}
        {#1}
    } \ifnum\ii<#2 \repeat
}
```

But this gives the error `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].` Moreover the messages printed in the terminal `1 1 1 1 1 ...` show that the counter remains fixed to 1 and that the loop goes on forever.

Could you explain why I had to *remove the curly braces* in order to obtain the following working solution?

```
% working
\def\punishment#1#2{
    \newcount\ii\ii=0
    \loop
        \advance\ii by 1 
        \message{\the\ii}
        {#1}
    \ifnum\ii<#2 \repeat
}
```

More specifically, why did the first attempt behave that way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`{...}`  forms a group, and `\advance\ii by 1` is a local assignment so reverted at the end of the group.

so `\ii` is always 0 in `\ifnum\ii<#2`  and it loops forever.

Your definition may not be used in plain tex at all, if you use  plain tex you get the error

```
Runaway definition?
#1#2-> 
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning definition of \punishment.
<inserted text> 
                }
<to be read again> 
                   \newcount 
l.2     \newcount
                 \ii\ii=0
?
```

as `\newcount` is `\outer` so not allowed in a definition.

In latex it is not an error but still you should move `\newcount` outside the definition so you only allocate one counter not a new counter each time the macro is used.

Comment: Note that latex does not include plain.tex and most commands (including `\newcount` and `\loop`) have different definitions, even when they have the same name as commands defined in plain TeX.

Answer (score 8):

Braces have a dual job in TeX:

1. they can be used to form a group, or
2. they can enclose a single ***undelimited*** argument to a macro.

In the latter case, there is no group involved: if you do

```
\def\foo#1{(#1)}
\foo{\it italics} and still italics
```

you will see that `\it` is not scoped, but continues on. Indeed, the argument passed to `\mytext` is just `italics` and macro replacement produces

```
(\it italics) and still italics
```

Conversely, if you do

```
\def\foo{(}
\foo{\it italics} and upright text
```

you will get

```
({\it italics} and upright text
```

because there was no argument grabbing, so the isolated left brace opens a group.

Now we can look at the definition of `\loop`:

```
527 \def\loop#1\repeat{\def\body{#1}\iterate}
528 \def\iterate{\body \let\next\iterate \else\let\next\relax\fi \next}
529 \let\repeat=\fi % this makes \loop...\if...\repeat skippable
```

(line numbers refer to `plain.tex`). Well, `\loop` seems to take an argument, doesn't it?

Yes, but the argument is ***delimited*** and consists of everything up to the first occurrence of `\repeat` at the same brace level. In this case TeX strips braces only if the argument turns out to have the form

```
{<tokens>}
```

and stripping those outer braces doesn't lead to unbalanced braces.

In your case the argument is

```
{•\advance\ii by•1•\message{\the\ii}•{#1}•}•\ifnum\ii<#2•
```

where `•` denotes a space token, so no brace stripping is done and the isolated left brace opens a group. At the end of the group, the value of `\ii` is reverted back to what it was before, which explains why you always get `1`, because after the group `\ii` is given back the value `0`.

If you instead do

```
\newcount\ii\ii=0
\def\punishment#1#2{
    \loop {
        \advance\ii by 1 
        \message{\the\ii}
        {#1}
    \ifnum\ii<#2 }\repeat
}
```

you will see that it works, because the outer braces are stripped off as they don't leave unbalanced ones.

Of course, this is not the best way to program the loop, for several reasons:

1. those outer braces are useless and hinder readability of the code;
2. there's plenty of spurious spaces;
3. there's no line breaking.

Note that `\newcount` is outer in plain TeX (you shouldn't test plain TeX code with LaTeX), so it cannot appear inside the replacement text of a macro, so I moved it outside.

The initialization `\ii=0` should instead go inside the macro.

```
\newcount\ii
\def\punishment#1#2{%
  \ii=0
  \loop
    \advance\ii by 1 
    \message{\the\ii}%
    #1\endgraf % \par wouldn't work in plain
  \ifnum\ii<#2\repeat
}
```

I'd not use braces around `#1`. Why `\repeat` just after `#2`?

OK, let's do a test.

```
\newcount\ii
\def\punishment#1#2{%
  \ii=0
  \loop
    \advance\ii by 1 
    \message{\the\ii}%
    #1
  \ifnum\ii<#2
\repeat
}

\newcount\test
\test=4

\punishment{Test}{4}

\punishment{Test}{\test}

\bye
```

The output ought to be the same, shouldn't it?

[image]

Move `\repeat` or add `\relax` just after `#2` to get

[image]

Exercise: find out why.